# Stripes URL prefix as request parameter

Tags: java, url, stripes, urlbinding

I'm trying to build a way for my application to have a URL pattern/scheme like that of applications like Twitter. For example myapplication.com/username where the username is an actual username treated as a parameter. This parameter will be used to display the user related page. My application also has this URL scheme where the username is a prefix for other resources e.g. myapplication.com/username/accountsettings or myapplication.com/username/profile. The username acts some sort of sub-context path.

As the title suggests, I'm using Stripes for it. What I'm doing now is create a custom ActionResolver where I take out the first non-empty string from the URL binding (the username in this case) since my ActionBeans do not take into account the username prepended to the URL. So for example, the action bean that handles myapplication.com/username/accountsettings is only bound to /accountsettings.

When I tried to use the custom ActionResolver as ActionResolver.Class init param for the Stripes filter, it doesn't seem to be working. It seems like it's still using the default ActionResolver. How do I alter this?

Also, is there an easier/more intuitive way to do this? I'm not very familiar with Stripes and URL bindings so is there a facility in Stripes that would allow me to do this without extending/altering the framework components?

Thanks.

Comment: What webserver and language are you using, I believe it is Java but you have not tagged it as Java. There might be some URL rewriting solution that could solve this very easy, thats what most sites use but then we need a little more information on your platform.

Comment: Yes it's in Java using Stripes framework. Right now I'm testing it out with Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with lucas, URL mappings should be done by [UrlBinding](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Annotation+Reference#AnnotationReference-@UrlBinding) annotation. There is no need to start messing around with URL remapping filters, that will only break the Stripes system in generating correct URL’s for you.

This is how it should look like:

```
@UrlBinding("{username}/profile/")
public class MyProfileAction implements ActionBean {
    private ActionBeanContext context;
    private String username;

    public ActionBeanContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(ActionBeanContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @DefaultHandler
    public Resolution view() {
        return new ForwardResolution(“/WEB-INF/MyProfile.jsp”);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so like I said with my other comment, I've already tried this one. But now, I'm having problems with URL bindings in Stripes. I have and action bean bound to /{username}/home and another to /{username}/account/logout. When load my changes and try to access /myuser/home, Stripes says the URL is bound to multiple action beans. I don't understand why.

Comment: Unless you overwrite the default ActionResolver.Class each URL mapped should be unique. Thus could it be that you have more ActionBeans in your project than these two?

Comment: Well I'm thinking that /{username}/home and /{username}/account/logout are different from each other. I do have more action beans in the application but only these two have been modified using this URL binding scheme. Based on my searches, it seems that Stripes URL binding really have issues with these kinds of URLs. It can work well when the parameters are at the end of the URL but not when they're in the beginning.

Comment: In that case you have to customize the default "ActionResolver.class" so it can select the correct Action Bean, please see the Configuration reference: http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Configuration+Reference

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon [URL Rewrite Filter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) and it seems to fit the needs of my application so far.

Comment: No need for URL rewrite filter when using Stripes! See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stripes does have this built in.  It's called the **@URLBinding** annotation, and it was included in Stripes 1.5.  There is some documentation [here](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/action/UrlBinding.html), and there was more in the [Stripes book](http://pragprog.com/titles/fdstr/stripes) IIRC.

> **@UrlBinding("/foo/{bar}/{baz}")** maps
>   the action to "/foo" and indicates
>   that the "bar" and "baz" parameters
>   may be embedded in the URL. In this
>   case, the URL /foo/abc/123 would
>   invoke the action with bar set to
>   "abc" and baz set to "123".

Comment: I've seen this one before but I haven't tried it yet. This can be helpful with the URL Rewrite Filter.

Comment: Better, you don't need a URL rewrite filter any more!

Comment: I've just tested this one and it works. I'll be using this as primary means for the application to handle URLs but I'm still using URL Rewrite filter for other things that @UrlBinding can't handle directly.